# Angular Directive restriction 'C' not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to write a directive with restrict `C` in **TypeScript** but the link is not getting called. What am I missing?

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/jquery.tooltipster/jquery.tooltipster.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../stationstaff.ts" />

module App.StationStaff {

    class BedDetailDirective implements ng.IDirective {

        public static factory() {
            var directive = () => new BedDetailDirective();
            directive.$inject = [];

            return directive;
        }

        public restrict = "C";

        public link($scope: ng.IScope, element: JQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var content = "<div class='tooltipster-header'><span>Art: Elektrisch</span></div><div class='tooltipster-body'><span>ID: BSHR1114</span><span>Ort: Station SR.1 - Raum: 10</span><span>Hersteller: Hill-Rom</span><span>Nächster Service: 31.05.2015</span></div>";

            $element.tooltipster({
                content: content,
                contentAsHTML: true,
                animation: "fade",
                theme: "hpm-tooltipster",
                position: "right",
                trigger: "click",
                functionReady(e) {
                    e.addClass("hpm-item-active");
                },
                functionAfter(e) {
                    e.removeClass("hpm-item-active");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    angular.module("appStationStaff", [])
        .directive("tooltip", BedDetailDirective.factory());
}



<ion-view ng-controller="bedFinderResultController as vm">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
            <div class="item item-balanced item-icon-right item-royal hpm-item-medium" ng-repeat="bed in vm.beds">
                <div class="hpm-item-icon text-center ion-ios-information-outline tooltip">
                </div>
                <div class="hpm-bed-availability-red"></div> <!-- TODO: Color should come from controller -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="hpm-item-title">
                                <span>Type: {{bed.type}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="hpm-item-subtitle">
                                <span>{{bed.location}} - Room: {{bed.room}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the setup of your directive in the factory:

```
 public static factory() {
   var directive = () => new BedDetailDirective();
   directive.$inject = [];
   return directive(); // NOTE: calling the function
 }
```

A directive definition for registration is a function that returns an object and that object is the directive definition object (DDO).

What you are returning above is a function that returns a function that returns the DDO. Just make the change to return the execution of that function instead of the function itself.